# Rose leaf edges are browning , please help?

Tags: leaves, indoors, roses

I have an indoor rose. Some time ago I added some succulent potting mix to it, then I noticed the tips are turning brown. I changed its soil again.
I feel it's not as fresh as before. Any idea what should I do? I love her so much, she is a very very beautiful and good girl, and I'm apprehensive about it.
Any help would be appreciated.[image: rose leaf edges became brown]

Answer (score 1):

It is my personal experience that small indoor roses definitely are not easy growers.

You added "succulent potting mix" to the soil. I guess the reason to do that was troubles with overwatering and yellow leaves.

Then the soil dried out quicker than usual, and then the tips of the leaves became [brown](https://www.pennington.com/all-products/fertilizer/resources/how-to-save-brown-tipped-plants).

To prevent yellow leaves, I suggest that you

- check the drainage of the pot according to [this guide](https://www.gardenerreport.com/how-to-care-for-indoor-miniature-roses)
- consider that unsatisfying light conditions can cause yellow leaves
  too
- try to use a indoor fertilizer when watering, if you have not done that recently

It is my experience that often the trick to avoid brown tips is to check the need for watering **daily** at least until you feel familiar with the needs. It does not mean that you should provide water frequently as emphasized in the linked guide:

> To test whether your rose needs watering, simply place your finger
> into the soil about an inch down and see if you can detect any
> moisture. If the soil is still moist then you can wait a day or so
> before watering. If the soil is on the dry side then this is the
> perfect time to water.
>
> Remember roses like the soil to be somewhat dry in between watering so
> do not feel you are neglecting your rose by waiting for the soil to
> dry out.
>
> The aim is to water once per week but if the soil feels dry and the
> temperature in your house is particularly hot because of warmer
> weather, give your rose another watering.

Comment: I'm so grateful for your response. I will follow your advice and update you on her situation. So many thanks